# Ruby on Rails - Losing form values after failed validation on some fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I have a form

```
     <%= f.input :firstname, :label => "Forename", :input_html => { :placeholder => "Forename"} %>
     <%= f.input :surname, :label => "Surname", :input_html => { :placeholder => "Surname", :"data-

  <%= f.input :publiclyfundedteaching, :label => "Publicly funded teaching (PFT)", :input_html => {:style => 'width:7%', :id => "publiclyfundedteaching", :value => '0', :onkeyup => "myFunction()"} %>

  <%= f.input :non_publicly_funded_teaching, :label => "Non-Publicly Funded teaching (NPFT)", :input_html => {:style => 'width:7%', :id => "non_publicly_funded_teaching", :value => '0', :onkeyup => "myFunction()"} %>
```

and controller

```
def create


@submission = Submission.new(submission_params)
@email = @submission.email
puts @email
if @submission.save
  flash[:notice] = 'Your user was successfully created.'
  
  else

@staffform = Form.find(10000)
   @livestatus = @staffform.status
   puts @staffform.status
   puts "not saved"

  puts @submission.errors.full_messages
render :new
  end
```

And Model:

```
validates :firstname, presence: true
validates :surname, presence: true
validates :email, presence: true


validates :total, numericality: { only_integer: true, equal_to: 100}


# First group

validates :publiclyfundedteaching, numericality: { only_integer: true }
validates :non_publicly_funded_teaching, numericality: { only_integer: true }
validates :support_for_teaching, numericality: { only_integer: true }
```

The problem is the :publiclyfundedteaching, non_publicly_funded_teaching and support_for_teaching for teaching fields do not retain there values after validation. Email, surname and firstname do.

Please advise how I can get around this.
I guess this has something to do with the value attribute on these fields?

Much appreciated!!

Comment: Can you please tell us what does submission_params look like before creating the new record? The option `only_integer: true` checks the field against regular expression /\A[+-]?\d+\z/ 
Note that "2" will match but "2.0" won't.

Comment: Thanks for the reply see comment below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See how you have `:value => '0'` in the form fields for both `:publiclyfundedteaching` and `:non_publicly_funded_teaching` (the third one you mentioned is not in your form).
They will set the value in the fields to 0 even if you reload a previously filled form. You can either remove that or try to add an if statment like so (assuming submission is the model):

```
<%= f.input :publiclyfundedteaching, label: "Publicly funded teaching (PFT)", input_html: { style: 'width:7%', id: "publiclyfundedteaching", value: @submission.publiclyfundedteaching || 0, onkeyup: "myFunction()" } %>
```

Comment: Thank you v much Clara. Much appreciated. Exactly what i need

Comment: You're very welcome, I would be happy if you can accept my answer!

Answer (score 0):

In `submission_params` you probably have something like:

```rb
def submission_params
  params.require(:your_model_name).permit(:firstname, :surname, :email)
end
```

this removes any other fields to protect them from data forged by client

if you want a field to be writeable - add it to permitted

Comment: Many thanks!I probably didn't explain the problem properly. essentially when validation kicks with the form error messages are displayed , the fields values for :firstname, :surname, :email are still there but we have lost the other values that the user has inputted for the numerical fields. possible due to the value attribute initially associated with those fields.